# image.fromfile() cannont use relative path "~/folder/file"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, relative-path, system.io.file

Greeting people,

I'm having a bit of trouble with loading images from file.
When i want to use my files anywhere else i use a relative path like "~/folder/file"
but when i try to create an image using that method it cannot be found.
Since i'm not willing to use absolute paths and change the accordingly after every publish does anyone know how to set the relative path in this case?

These particulare jpgs are in the Vouchers/ directory in the project's root but cannot be found through "~/Vouchers/spring.jpg" for example

Comment: `~` has no meaning in terms of the file system. Try something like `./folder/file`.

Comment: doesn't work. Neither does ../folder/file

Comment: Would using `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Vouchers/spring.jpg")` be an option?

Comment: It would indeed. Thanks a lot man very useful tool. Can you give it as an aswer so i can give you dem points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid hardcoding absolute paths but still be able to provide absolute paths via relative paths, just let the system put them together for you one the fly:

`System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Vouchers/spring.jpg")`